# @Autowire failing with @Repository

Tags: spring, annotations, repository, autowired

I am not being able to make @Autowire annotation work with a @Repository annotated class.

I have an interface:

```
public interface AccountRepository {
    public Account findByUsername(String username);
    public Account findById(long id);
    public Account save(Account account);
}
```

And the class implementing the interface **annotated with @Repository**:

```
@Repository
public class AccountRepositoryImpl implements AccountRepository {
    public Account findByUsername(String username){
        //Implementing code
    }
    public Account findById(long id){
        //Implementing code            
    }
    public Account save(Account account){
        //Implementing code
    }
}
```

In another class, I need to use this repository to find an account by the username, so I am using autowiring, but I am checking if it works and the accountRepository instance **is always null**:

```
@Component
public class FooClass {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    ...

    public barMethod(){
        logger.debug(accountRepository == null ? "accountRepository is NULL" : "accountRepository IS NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

I have also set the packages to scan for the components  (`sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String [] {"com.foo.bar"});`), and it does autowire other classes annotated with @Component for instance, but in this one annotated with @Repository, it is always null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you getting a reference to `FooClass`? Are you saying `FooClass foo = new FooClass();`?

Comment: You found the problem, I was getting a reference with a `new` instead of autowiring too. Post a response if you want to accept it as the right one. Thanks indeed!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you're instantiating the bean yourself with `new`, so that Spring isn't aware of it. Inject the bean instead, or make the bean `@Configurable` and use AspectJ.

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that you haven't configured your Spring annotations to be enabled. I would recommend taking a look at your component scanning annotations. For instance in a Java config application:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo" })
```

... or XML config:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" />
```

If your FooClass is not under the base-packages defined in that configuration, then the @Autowired will be ignored.

As an additional point, I would recommend trying @Autowired(required = true) - that *should* cause your application to fail on start-up rather than waiting until you use the service to throw a NullPointerException. However, if annotations are not configured, then there will be no failure.

You should test that your autowiring is being done correctly, using a JUnit test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = MyConfig.class, 
    loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AccountRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldWireRepository() {
        assertNotNull(accountRepository);
    }

}
```

This should indicate whether your basic configuration is correct. The next step, assuming that this is being deployed as a web application, would be to check that you have put the correct bits and pieces in your web.xml and foo-servlet.xml configurations to trigger Spring initialisation.

Comment: I added `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo" })` and my class is under this package.

I also tried to add `<context:annotation-config />` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

FooClass needs to be instancied by Spring to have his depencies managed.
Make sure FooClass is instancied as a bean (@Component or @Service annotation, or XML  declaration).

Edit : `sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan` is looking for JPA/Hibernate annotations whereas `@Repository` is a Spring Context annotation.
`AccountRepositoryImpl` should be in the Spring `component-scan` scope

Regards,

Comment: I make a mistake when writing the post, FooClass is already annotated with @Component, I will edit the question to add it. Thanks indeed

Comment: But @Component is also a Spring Context annotation and it is working fine with other classes annotated with Component.

Comment: But in which package is `AccountRepositoryImpl` ?
And in what is the Spring `context:component-scan` ? Are they matching ?

Comment: FYI - You don't need to annotate a class as Component (or any other stereotype) for Autowired annotations within it to work. Not everything in the application needs to be a Spring bean.

Comment: Hum... without a custom Context lookup or a BeanFactory, can't see how Spring could autowire objects he doesn't manage.
Do you have a XML sample of injecting bean into non-bean ?
Edit : SpringBeanAutowiringSupport would do the job, too

Comment: `AccountRepositoryImpl` is under the `com.foo.bar` package, which is the configured one in the Spring context:component-scan.

Comment: If you have a logging configuration try to put `org.springframework.context` at `DEBUG` level to ensure all your beans are properly created.